# why doesn't this simple bulma example work? (straight from their site)

Tags: css, frameworks

I copied a basic example from the site and included the css file, but the columns aren't being styled.  What am I missing?

https://jsfiddle.net/bLm2rgoz/6/

Here's the template:

```
<div class="columns">
  <div class="column">1</div>
  <div class="column">2</div>
  <div class="column">3</div>
  <div class="column">4</div>
  <div class="column">5</div>
</div>
```

Of course, I'm including https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.2.3/css/bulma.css

Comment: Columns are working on resolution `>=768`.

Comment: Looks to be working for me. What are you expecting to see?

Comment: @thebluefox  Columns automatically sized:  http://bulma.io/documentation/grid/columns/   I only see the contents, no styles applied

Comment: .column CSS is applied if you inspect the elements..

Comment: @Goombah  Doh!  I just had to drag the screen a little wider.  I guess I figured it would automatically resize for smaller screens.

Answer (score 0):

This will only address the responsiveness of the 5 columns! You can demonstrate the responsiveness by `widening` and `shrinking` the fiddler-view. (Hint: Drag the left-side of the view panel to do so)

Expected & Observed: row of `1 2 3 4 5` when the view is wide, column of

`1`

`2`

`3`

`4`

`5`

when the view is not wide.

If you're trying to style the columns, please be more specific on which styles you want : )

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because they are not even using the same CSS library they tell you to use to get that result (and yes, that sucks!)

If you view the source code on the example site, you see that it is actually:
`<p class="bd-notification is-primary">First column</p>` and not just `First column`.

So we edit our HTML and it *still* doesn't work. So back to the source and we discover that the CSS being referenced is in `bulma-docs.min.css`, and *not* in the CSS from the CDN or download that you are told to use (which is just `bulma.min.css` or `bulma.css`).

So we look at that and add some new CSS to the `<head>` of our HTML...

```
<style>
p.nice {
        background-color: #00d1b2;
        color: white;
        border-radius: .375em;
        font-weight: 600;
        padding: 1.25rem 0 1.25rem 0;
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

and change the example to be like this...

```
div class="columns">
  <div class="column"><p class="nice">First column</p></div>
  <div class="column"><p class="nice">Second column</p></div>
  <div class="column"><p class="nice">Third column</p></div>
  <div class="column"><p class="nice">Fourth column</p></div>
</div>
```

and then it finally looks like the example on the web site.

Dear library/framework developers... We love you and the work you do, especially when you document it and make nice examples. But when you claim using your framework is "very simple" and "just copy this code", then the result should look the same as your example. Don't use different code to what you are putting in the example, unless you also state very clearly that it will look/act differently and why. Remember, even experienced programmers are "newbies" to your framework, and having to waste time trying to figure out why it isn't working like the example can be really infuriating.

Comment: I don't think the rant is in place. Styling around columns is added only for presentation. Whoever reads the whole documentation will understand that "Columns" are supposed to be used only for layout purposes.